# Importing csv file: factors instead of numbers. Retrieving a string vector from a list

Tags: r, categorical-data

i) I was importing as csv file of numbers, which is now available as a list L. From applying

```
sapply(L, class)
```

I know that my numbers are now factors. Why is this? I used this a couple of times and I always got a list of numbers. And now the important question: how can I translate these factors in numbers without loosing the structure of the list (i.e. the member names)?

ii) Given the list L as

```
L <- list(c(1,1,3),c(2,4),rep(c(2,3),each=7))
names(L)<-c("A","B","C")
```

Suppose we only have the resulting list L. How can I retrieve the vector of strings c("A","B","C") from L?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible you ended up with some character data in there somewhere? That would make all the numbers character. If possible identify a small subset of the data that has the same problem and give that data.

Comment: Did you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you read your file?

Comment: In (i), I would just read the data in again, this time using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the function used to read the data. Chances are you have a non-numeric character in there somewhere.  In (ii), call `names(L)`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I read in the file again using stringsAsFactors = FALSE. Now my numbers are of type character. How would you transform them to numbers? I could make a matrix, but is there an other way which preserves the list format?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I cannot answer my own question.

Combining your comments with the `dec` command solved my problem. Everything worked perfectly well reading in the csv file using:

    temp <- read.csv2("my_file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, dec = ".")

where `dec= "."` stands for the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

Combining your comments with the `dec` command solved my problem. Everything worked perfectly well reading in the csv file using:

```
temp <- read.csv2("my_file.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, dec = ".")
```

where `dec= "."` stands for the decimal separator.